# Does HttpWebRequest vs HttpClient effect response time badly

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpclient

There is a web service. I am calling it through HttpWebRequest, sometimes it is taking more than 10 sec to respond. Generally, it takes 50ms. Does moving to HttpClient solve this?

Comment: It depends why it is occurring. It might help, it might not.

Comment: No believe the answer is no. It might depend on how you develop your API and also how you call it. Show us the code at least.

Comment: API code doesn't belong to me. @mjwills can you specify a case where it might help?. Thanks.

Comment: It might be quicker for you to try using `HttpClient` and see whether it helps.

Comment: Here is your answer: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3198673/application-development/my-two-cents-on-webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest.html

Comment: Will change to HttpClient and see how it works. Thanks.